Anime with Monster fighting highschoolers
I remember an Anime I watched before 2015, which contained the following:

The male protagonist was kind of best friends & rivals with a girl
The reason for the rivalry was some sort of heredity rivalry from the families
At night the two would don Hakama and a white(?) Kosode, sleeves tied up with Tasuki
Dressed like that and armed with paper figures they'd go and fight monsters/spirits, for example at their own high school.


Kekkaishi
It took me a while to find, but... here it is:

These are the Protagonist (right) and his SO (left) wearing their 'battle uniform'. The checkered band on the girl's shoulder? That's the Tasuki, and she's the one in white Kosode - Yoshimori wears black...
The reason for the high school playing a prominent role? It's their usual battleground!

In the present day, Yoshimori Sumimura and Tokine Yukimura, heirs of the Hazama clan, are the kekkaishi (結界師) that protect Karasumori (which is located on the grounds of the school they attend).  (Wiki)


Thankfully, Yoshimura isn't the only one helping to keep the baddies at bay. His childhood friend and neighbor, Tokine Yukimura, joins him in this righteous battle. Despite the fact that they are from rival clans, these two make a fantastic team.  (myanimelist)

